# PHP pagination depending on table's column value in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pagination

I need to do pagination for table contain the following:

- id.
- name.
- type (this contains: bad, good, great).

I need to order the result depending on type, first to appear 'great' then 'good' and last 'bad'. For example: I have 36 rows with type 'great', 25 with type 'good' and 13 with type 'bad' (total number of rows is 74), and I'm going to display 10 at each page. So at page 4 there will be 6 of type 'great' and 4 of type 'good'.

How to do such pagination?

Comment: You need to count total amount of rows matching a criteria, then you need to generate and offset for `LIMIT` clause using that amount of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On click of a button (arrow, , submit input, whatever suits you) send a parameter via get or post with the page number (starting with 0).

On your server side get the page number that you sent, check if it's valid and clean it off hazardous stuff (like injections of all sorts). Multiply it by some "pagesize" and then query the database for a range of records (order by type, id).

Example: 74 records, page 4, you pass page=3 as GET parameter and set it to some variable ($page), multiply it by page size and put into a query with `offset` and `limit`:

```
 SELECT * FROM table
 ORDER BY type DESC, id 
 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 30
```

where offset is calculated as `$page` * `$pageSize`, and limit is `$pageSize`. As a result you get 10 records from the range 31-40, sorted by type.

In this concrete example you can just alphabetically sort your types descending (since 'great' > 'good' > 'bad'), but you might need more advanced sorting for more different types.